# cannot create regular file '/usr/Desktop': Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, git

Im trying to git clone

```
git clone cp /usr/Desktop
```

But it comes up with `cannot create regular file '/usr/Desktop': Permission denied`
every time

Comment: It's unclear what you are actually trying to do, but it's clear and understandable that you can't create `/usr/Desktop` as a non-privileged user. If you could possibly describe a bit about what you want to achieve by that command, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/Desktop` is not where you GUI desktop directory is stored.  It's most likely in `/home/<username>/Desktop`